# It is possible insert dummy (dash) into first row data use select statement in oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
table_A 

col_color  col_name  col_qty
   -           -        -   <----- dummy dash
  RED        APPLE      2
  YEL        BANANA     1
  GRN      GREEN_APPLE  3
```

Hi, it is posible to insert first row of dummy dash for viewing not store into database
use oracle sql plus ?

Anyone help is much apprecited.

Comment: Not without "messing up" the integer datatype of col_qty, if you want a dash in the result, the column will have to be converted to a string or similar datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `UNION` two data sets; one contains *dummy dashes*, while another contains "real" data. Note that dashes are considered to be **strings**, which means that you'll have to cast other datatypes to character datatype (see `to_char(deptno)` in my example):

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select 1 rn, '-' deptno     , '-' dname, '-' loc from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 2 rn, to_char(deptno), dname    , loc     from dept
  5    )
  6  select deptno, dname, loc
  7  from temp
  8  order by rn, deptno;

DEPTNO     DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
-          -              -
10         ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
20         RESEARCH       DALLAS
30         SALES          CHICAGO
40         OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

The `rn` column is used to correctly sort the output (dashes first, the rest of data next).

Comment: yes, this work.. but it is possible only use select statement ?

Comment: This **is** a SELECT statement.

Comment: ya, because i did't use 'with' so i just run select statement as your suggested. it work! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use 'with', then how about this?

```
 (
 SELECT '-' COL_COLOR
      , '-' COL_NAME
      , '-' COL_QTY
  FROM DUAL
 )
 UNION ALL
 (
 SELECT *
   FROM table_A
 )
```

I think this way is the best way not using 'with'.

Comment: Why might a reader want to avoid `with`? That'd be useful to add to your answer.